# C++ Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 best and easiest way to detect memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Currently I have a solution but I am not sure if it's alright in every scenario. Can I check if there is any memory leaks in the program with this solution? If anyone can offer a better solution please do not hesitate to share the answer. Thanks!

My example code here:

```
int *array = new int[5];
delete[] array; //so no memory leaks

//Memory leak check.
if (_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()) {
    std::cout << "Memory leaks!\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "No leaks\n";
}

cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: There is Microsoft Debug Diag tool. Maybe now it has different name. It creates really good leak reports with callstakcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I found an other solution - Can someone agree with it?*** (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2017 )

**1st step** - create 3 breakpoints. **!!! The last breakpoint should have put after the return - not in line!**

[image: 1st step]

**2nd step** - Start debugging and creating snapshots. (Diagnostic Tool)

[image: 2nd step]

**3rd step** - Click on the second snapshot and see 3 variables allocated dynamically in the heap.

[image: 3rd step]

**4th step** - Click on the third snapshot that we made - so we took it after releasing memory of the 'a' pointer with: delete a; That's why the size here is only 8 bytes. (12 bytes - 4 bytes that we have just released)

[image: 4th step]

Comment: Good work but is not a solution, talking in terms of finding memory leaks. In a real program you will never know where to put the breakpoints and where to expect the leak. You only established the fact of memory allocation, but not yet the fact of the leak. And there is no callstack of allocation.

Comment: Memory leaks are caused by allocated - but not deallocated memory or not? If I set up two breakpoints - one at the entry and the other at the end of the program then it should indicate the de-allocated dynamic variables.

Comment: you are talking about trivial cases. You know exactly where to put the breakpoints, where it starts, where it finishes. In a real program you will not be able to do it.

Comment: The process of finding memory leak means taking a snapshot before starting the functionality suspected for leaks. Repeat this functionality N times and take second snapshot after these N repetition. Make the report of memory allocation between these two snapshots. The diagnostig tool should do a diff between the snapshots and report the memory allocations that were not freed, adding the callstacks of allocations. Ideally the count of leaking stask is a multiple of N, but it is not an axiom.

Comment: You diagnosed the memory leak means you have its full callstacs, so you can fix it in the code.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the best suited thing would be as you used in the first place, the `CRT` library and indeed the use of `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` as Microsoft documentation says:

> The _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks function determines whether a memory leak has occurred since the start of program execution.

Concerning your other doubt:

> but I am not sure if it's alright in every scenario

Per the microsoft documentation, it should log any memory leak occuring in your whole program even if it is in a class or anywhere where you might think as it:

> Dumps all the memory blocks in the debug heap when a memory leak has occurred

Also don't forget to `#define` the `_DEBUG` flag as mentionned here:

> When _DEBUG is not defined, calls to _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks are removed during preprocessing.

but nevertheless if you're making software you should use STL and use smart pointers.

Also you might have another way of checking a memory leak for a certain resource at a time, I use the memory tab provided by visual studio when debugging which is located in **debug > windows > memory > memory1** (Note: you'll have to be in debug mode to see the setting) then in the search bar you can type `array` so you go where your pointed to memory lives, and then you could just step into your program and see if the memory is nulled out or not.

**Note:**
This is more if you want to visually monitor one resource at a time and not if you want a whole dump of each possibly leaked resources.

Comment: Thank you! Does it also work effectively if I have different classes which have various memory allocations - ..and destructors?

Comment: No problem! and Yes with the CRT library it should detect them (Any time where you allocate memory as the documentation says: `Dumps all the memory blocks in the debug heap when a memory leak has occurred `), and for my technique you just type in the name of the pointer where you allocated memory and it should redirect you to it's virtual address in memory. Btw if this solved your answer don't forget to put the green checkmark :D

Comment: @Tivi Updated my answer and added a reply :)

Comment: Thank you! I am currently trying to find how to do it by your way. In the debug > windows...I cannot really find memory,memory1 - Do I need to create breakpoints?

Comment: @Tivi yes create a breakpoint at your entry point and then go into debug, sorry

Comment: Oh okey I got it! ..For example here I got memory1-4. All I see here are addresses - can I make a search for a variable? I mean I can't really find a searchbar here.

Comment: yes, you can check this here: https://i.imgur.com/37nGrqr.png  where you see `address:`, also you can do `&` and the name of the variable.

Comment: Thanks! So for example here: https://imgur.com/a/1rFp5ko I should see it's nulled out.

Comment: I can't see what memory is nulled out or not - it just changes the colour from white to red - after I release the memory by delete.